# Tomcat blocks all requests until initial startup is finished

Tags: tomcat, web-deployment, war, tomcat10

During the upgrade to Tomcat 10.1 I noticed a behavior causing the initial startup phase to take several minutes. If a web application tries to contact the Tomcat connector during its deployment, the request gets blocked. When no timeout is specified, this will pause the startup process indefinitely.

In order to test this, I created a small WAR using [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) with a small component:

```java
@Component
public class Initializer {

    @Autowired
    public Initializer() {
        System.out.println("Init!");
        new RestTemplate().getForObject("http://localhost:8080/", String.class);
    }

}
```

If the resulting WAR file is deployed to a running Tomcat instance, the deployment is done in no time. However, if Tomcat is stopped and started again, it will halt after printing "Init!" on the console.

How can I make certain that my web-app behaves identical regardless if it is deployed on startup or redeployed later?

Comment: You created the deadlock yourself, what would you expect? You are calling the app that you are deploying from the app. The constructor will block because the request will be blocked by tomcat, this will now be a blocking issue. So basically you did it all yourself.

Comment: This also happens if the root webapp is already deployed and the test webapp is deployed under /test. In this case there is no deadlock but the issue is still present. And even if there were a deadlock, deployment should behave the same regardless of the time of deployment.

Comment: Well no, because at a restart all the apps will start at once and thus this causes to block the start of the ROOT app and thus won't start. With a clean deployment the ROOT app is already started. So no they won't behave the same because different things happen.

Comment: Okay, let's try a different approach: If I replace the RestTemplate call with a Thread.sleep, I am unable to request any URL in the browser until the sleep is done and all webapps are deployed. This is unexpected, why can't I access web-apps that are already deployed during startup?

Comment: Because the Tomcat developers made a decision to only serve requests once the server is fully up. Otherwise, you'd get unpredictable behavior: If 1000 requests are coming in for a yet-uninitialized app, the behavior would depend on the timing of your request to your already-deployed app. Sometimes that'd work, sometimes the queue would be clogged by those requests that can't yet be served

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you're describing tomcat's actual behavior, and on top shouldn't make the initialization of your app dependent on _any_ external resource, be it local or external, without preparing for that initialization to fail and be retried. But the main reason is: The tomcat developers have decided to only serve requests once _all_ deployed applications are initialized, up and running (see my request above)

Comment: @OlafKock Then why is it possible for a web-app to request itself during redeployment? And why is the block during the startup process performed for the whole connector and not for the web-app which is currently starting?

I would like to know if there is some configuration settings that I miss.

Comment: Why should it be impossible? (especially through http) No runtime environment knows where that outgoing socket connection is going to.

Comment: I am not sure if we talk about the same thing. Why should it make any difference if I (1) start Tomcat without any webapps and copy all WAR files into the webbapp directory or (2) start Tomcat with all WAR files already in the directory?

Comment: We face this problem also for spring cloud config clients which are need config from config server (running on the same tomcat) and only after they get the config - then clients are started. Now config server is blocked, because clients did not finished the start .... real deadlock.  Would appreciate, if could be configure in tomcat - do not block requests to named URLs or to all. Now I do not see other way than run config server outside of tomcat.

Comment: This current tomcat behavior is really bad for apps which are dependent on other app in the same tomcat.